# Call CUDA C function from Fortran: which Fortran compiler, libraries and compiler options do I have to use?

Tags: nvidia, compiling, cuda, c, fortran

I want to call a CUDA C function in a separate file from a Fortran program from 2003. I want to use the `nvcc` command for compilation of the .cu file. Which compiler do I have to use, GNU Fortran or NVIDIA Fortran? Which libraries are needed for the CUDA C object? I use CUDA 12.3 and have the NVIDIA HPC SDK 24.3 installed. Finally I had success in compiling the program, but I got an segmentation fault error at runtime.